# dmesg has different identifier types for the same device, how to unify them?

Tags: linux, dmesg

In my Linux I use many devices, increasingly popular USB sticks. Thus I depend on the tool dmesg.

dmesg is very, very good, very powerfull but in one aspect there is a problem, I am not able to cope with.

dmesg uses two different identifier types for devices.

E.g.

```
usb 4-1.3.4.4
```

and

```
sd 7:0:0:0
```

But there is nowhere a message that these two identifiers belong to the same device.

Sometimes I find a referral to a host number. In this example it may be "host 7".

So I can figure to myself the that the data reported by

```
usb 4-1.3.4.4
```

and

```
sd 7:0:0:0
```

belong to the same device. But I cannot read that.

Is there perhaps an option, a switch which I do not know.

The utility "lshw" shows the correlation. But it is tedious to use lshw in addition to dmesg.

Regards.